# How do I cite a SDS in AMA format?

Tags: citations, citation-style

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I could cite a material safety data sheet (for a chemical compound) in the AMA format? An example would be appreciated, because I couldn't find anything helpful online.

Comment: Is the source available online?

Answer (score 1):

You should cite it as a book and include additional information if it is electronically available.

> Author Surname Author Initial. *Title*. City: Publisher; Year Published:Pages Used. [Available at: http://Website URL. Accessed Month DD, YYYY.]

Example:

> Lenga RE and Votoupal KL. *The Sigma-Aldrich library of regulatory and safety data.* Milwaukee: Aldrich Chemical Company; 1993:23-34

Comment: Wouldn't you need to include the name of the chemical of that specific SDS somewhere in the citation? Also, SDSs don't typically have named authors, as they usually cite the company name or a specific department as having prepared the sheet.

Comment: @Abdulla4496 Then replace the author name with that of the company. The specific chemical can be noted within the page interval. If the chemical is included as a separate section in the SDS, cite it as a book chapter.

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac Actually, it would be better to use the [technical report](http://www.amamanualofstyle.com/view/10.1093/jama/9780195176339.001.0001/med-9780195176339-div2-85) format, but that's rather close to book citations anyway.

Comment: @jakebeal I agree. I follow the same in BibTeX. But a lookup in the web recommends reports to be cited as books in AMA format.